# Initialize a sequence in Hsqldb Datamanager

Tags: sequence, hsqldb

I am using `hsqldb-1.8.0.10` and I want to use the sequence feature. I launch the `DatabaseManager` from the jar file as follows:

```
java -cp lib/hsqldb.jar org.hsqldb.util.DatabaseManager
```

I run these requests:

```
CREATE TABLE test (ID bigint)
CREATE SEQUENCE seq START WITH 1 INCREMENT BY 1
SELECT NEXT VALUE FOR seq FROM test
```

There is no output. If I insert some rows in the table, it works fine and displays `1`.

Is it a normal comportment? Is there a way to get a value with an empty table?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this is normal. The statement below returns one row for each row of the table. It doesn't matter what you put between SELECT and FROM (except aggregate functions).

```
 SELECT <anything you put here> FROM test
```

The `NEXT VALUE FOR seq` is like a function that return the next value each time it is called.

If you do not have to use version 1.8.0, use the latest version of HSQLDB as it supports a more extensive syntax.